# Conditional splitting a huge dataset in SAS

Tags: sas, bigdata

I need advice on how to split up a dataset efficiently (around 7 million rows and 280 columns).
My dataset contains the columns 'department' and 'classid' which are not unique. 
I would like to split my dataset depending on the department variable and the maximum number of observations (100k). Another limitation is shown by the following example:

```
Ex 1:

math_1 - 10k rows
math_2 - 80k rows
math_3 - 20k rows

Result 1:

math_1 + math_2 -> 90.000 rows - OK
math_3 -> 20.000 rows - OK

Ex. 2:

math_1 - 90k rows
math_2 - 80k rows
math_3 - 10k rows

Result 2.1:

math_1 + math_2 -> 100k rows (90k from math1, 10k from math2) -> not OK 
math_2 + math_3 -> 80k rows (70k from math_2, 10k from math_3 -> not OK
```

`math_2` is split across 2 tables although it would fit into one, so it should be split like this:

```
Result 2.2:

math_1 -> 90k rows -> OK
math_2 + math_3 -> 90k rows -> OK
```

Even if `math_2` would not fit into one table, I don't want it to be mixed with rows from another original table.

I tried to solve it with hash tables but am simply running out of memory because of the huge amount of columns.

Comment: 7 million isn't that much tbh, can you add some indexes instead to improve performance?  The rules are not fixed so that makes it harder to implement. It would be easier to just split by department and classid. It seems like breaking it up this way would also make it harder to use in the future because there isn't a well defined system so trying to find and use the data will be problematic.

Comment: https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2015/01/26/how-to-split-one-data-set-into-many/

Comment: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Split_Data_into_Subsets

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what hashes have to do here.

I would first summarize the data by Department and ClassID. Put the counts into a table. Then you can go down the table and create a new variable, called group. If the total > X amount then group + 1, else group is the same. This creates a variable that tells you your file structure.

Then use that data set with the groups to build your table split. I would recommend a CALL EXECUTE or DOSUBL to split the data into the subsets.

7 million with the max of 90K would be 8 + data sets....but it'll be a nightmare to work with to understand where you need to go get your data because it's not designed logically. So you'll always need to reference this table anyways.

```
data have;
input department $ classID $ num_records;
cards;
A math1 500
A math2 500
A math3 200
A math4 100
;
run;

data groups;
set have;
retain running_total;
running_total=sum(running_total, num_records);
if running_total >= 500 then do; group+1; running_total=num_records;
end;
run;
```

Use this with the links above to create the subsets if really, really desired.

Answer (score 0):

Create a test dataset to play with:
`data test; set original(keep=department classid); run;`

Use `PROC TABULATE` to get an overview of departments and classids.

Use `PROC SORT; BY department classid;` to sort your data.

Write SAS-Code to write SAS-Code to split your data:

> data  _null__;
>   put 'data classid1; set original; if classid="math_1"; run;';

So the code for splitting looks like this:

> data classid1;
>    set original;
>    if classid="math_1";
>   run;
>
> data classid2;
>    set original;
>    if classid="math_2";
>   run;